# How to send varying number of parameters using jsoup post/get?

Tags: java, connection, jsoup

I am scrapping pages for forms and then parsing/modifying the input parameters in a web page before sending the form post/get using jsoup.

After i modified the parameters i tried to send the post but there is a problem. The number of possible parameter pairs (name, value) depends on the form.

A normal post in jsoup looks like this:

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect(formDTO.getUrl())
                .data("username", "admin", "password", "admin", "login-php-submit-button", "Login")
                .method(getMethod(formDTO.getMethod()))
                .execute();
        Document doc = res.parse();
        System.out.println(doc.toString());
```

The `.data()` accepts pairs of parameters(name,value) and for multiple parameters, from what i found, I can either increase the number pairs in the `.data("username", "admin", "password", "admin")` or i can increase the number of `.data("name","value")`. But those solutions don't work if you don't know how many parameters you get.

I would like to not be forced to write a number of identical functions except having a varying number of .data() calls...

The javaDoc sais:

> Add a number of request data parameters. Multiple parameters may be
>   set at once, e.g.: .data("name", "jsoup", "language", "Java",
>   "language", "English"); creates a query string like:
>   ?name=jsoup&language=Java&language=English Parameters: keyvals - a set
>   of key value pairs. Returns: this Connection, for chaining

Is there a way to construct the post so that it can accept varying number of parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging i found that data() is overloaded with Map which can solve the varying number of parameters problem.

The documentation [here](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#requestBody-java.lang.String-)

> Connection    data(Collection data) Adds all of the
>   supplied data to the request data parameters Connection
>     data(Map data) Adds all of the supplied data to the
>   request data parameters Connection    data(String... keyvals) Add a
>   number of request data parameters.